# Azure Memory Allocation (Windows VM) for Python?

Tags: windows, memory, python, azure

I'm running a pretty intensive python script on a large Azure Windows VM. I'm using Enthought Canopy for my python environment.  The VM has 56gb of ram available... however in the task manager python only appears to be using 240mb of ram.  Is this a result of the process itself or memory allocation for python?  And if it is memory allocation, how can I allocate more memory?[image]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will only give memory to a process if and when the process asks for it. Windows won't give away memory to processes that don't ask for it, even if it has plenty of free memory.  Looks to me like Python isn't asking for any more than 243MB of memory.  Why do you feel like this Python script *should* be requesting more memory from the operating system?  Memory management is not usually an issue in Python, so I'm hesitant to go into things like `void* PyMem_Malloc(size_t n)` or whatever, because then  this turns into a Stackoverflow discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I guess I'm most curious to know if it is possible to write a process that takes so much time without taking memory or cpu usage.

Comment: Sure... `while (true) { sleep(10) }` <- I just wrote a program that takes a very long time to run, but takes almost no memory or CPU. ;) But on a more constructive note... yes it is possible, but we don't know what your program does or how it's written, so all we can do is guess.